# Passing hash as argument parameter

Tags: ruby

I have two hashes as so:

```
deploy = {}
config[:mysql] = {}
```

I also have a function as so:

```
def some_cool_function(mysql_config)
  {
     foo:bar
  }
end
```

When I call the function and assign the results to a hash as so:

```
deploy.mysql = some_cool_function(config.mysql)
```

I get `NoMethodError: undefined method mysql for #<Hash:0x000055a0f2929f58>`

It's possible the hash `mysql` just doesn't exist in the `config` hash, but i haven't investigated that option yet.

It looks right to me though, am I doing something incorrectly? I'm fairly new to the ruby language.

Comment: `Hash`es are not like `JSON`. Hash accessor methods are `[](val)` or `fetch(val)` so in your case `config.mysql` should be either `config[:mysql]` or `config.fetch(:mysql)` [Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html)

Comment: @engineersmnky perfect thank you.